# AngularJS "object" shows but not the actual model

Tags: angularjs

I can't seem to display `cause - description` in the drop down, instead it shows `[object Object]`. I'd like it to just select `cause` when it is selected. How can this be achieved?

In case the snippet cannot be viewed, here's the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/0jXmzfE6lsdTY5anzn9y?p=preview

my markup:

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {


     var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1O7M5gaEGlyE5gkOBARJrxJJMBYiTwz2THVjgbaTx9v8/od6/public/values?alt=json';
            var parse = function (entry) {
                console.log(entry);
                var description = entry.gsx$description.$t;
                var cause = entry.gsx$cause.$t;
                return {

                    description: description,
                    cause: cause
                };
            };
            $http.get(url)
                .then(function (response) {
                    var entries = response.data.feed.entry;

                    $scope.parsedEntries = [];
                    for (var key in entries) {
                        var content = entries[key];
                        $scope.parsedEntries.push(parse(content));
    
     }
                });


});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>




<div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

    <h4>Static arrays</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead-editable="false" uib-typeahead="cause for cause in parsedEntries | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
uib-typeahead="cause for cause in parsedEntries..."
```

Since this follows `ng-options` kinda syntax, you should be having

```
uib-typeahead="cause as cause.cause for cause in parsedEntries.."
```

since here `cause` is whole object with `description` and `cause`. If you want to read this syntax, it would be `value as label for collection` but in your case, since you hadn't provided anything for `label`, it was taking whole object and hence the `[object Object]` in the dropdown.

Here's your working example:

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  var url = 'https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/1O7M5gaEGlyE5gkOBARJrxJJMBYiTwz2THVjgbaTx9v8/od6/public/values?alt=json';
  var parse = function(entry) {
    var description = entry.gsx$description.$t;
    var cause = entry.gsx$cause.$t;
    return {
      description: description,
      cause: cause
    };
  };
  $http.get(url)
    .then(function(response) {
      var entries = response.data.feed.entry;

      $scope.parsedEntries = [];
      for (var key in entries) {
        var content = entries[key];
        $scope.parsedEntries.push(parse(content));
      }
    });
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">

<head>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-animate.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="example.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div class='container-fluid typeahead-demo' ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">

    <h4>Static arrays</h4>
    <pre>Model: {{selected | json}}</pre>
    <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead-editable="false" uib-typeahead="cause as cause.cause for cause in parsedEntries | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
cause.cause for cause in parsedEntries
```

That worked for me on your plnkr.

Answer (score 2):

the syntax for uib-typeahead is same to `ngOptions`. **documentation [here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#typeahead)**(Custom popup templates for typeahead's dropdown).

```
// value as text for item in items
cause as cause.description for cause in parsedEntries
```

**[working demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rha3WVppKCXGgLjRBEzf?p=preview)**.